# async redux. Error: modifiers may not emit actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I keep encountering what appears to be a parallel async redux error. At a high level I am trying to dispatch a bunch of async actions that fetch assets from urls.

I originally tried `redux-thunk` middleware and was encountering the same error. I have since moved to a "listener" style middleware which looks like:

```
// listener-middleware.js
// taken from https://medium.com/@alexandereardon/the-middleware-listener-pattern-better-asynchronous-actions-in-redux-16164fb6186f
export default (...listeners) => store => next => action => {
  // listeners are provided with a picture
  // of the world before the action is applied
  const preActionState = store.getState();

  // release the action to reducers before
  // firing additional actions
  next(action);


  // always async
  setTimeout(() => {
    // can have multiple listeners listening
    // against the same action.type
    listeners.forEach(listener => {
      if (listener[action.type]) {
        listener[action.type](action, store.dispatch, preActionState);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

The asset listener then looks like:

```
import { assetsFetchBinary, assetsReceiveBinary } from '../assets/actions.js';

export default {
  [assetsFetchBinary.toString()]: (action, dispatch, state) => {
    const assetPath = state.config.assetPath + '/' + action.payload.assetName;

    if(!state.assets[action.payload.assetName]){
      fetch(assetPath)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => {
          return dispatch(assetsReceiveBinary(action.payload.assetName, arrayBuffer))
        });
    }
  },
}
```

The store configuration and `applyMiddleware` is:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'minidux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import { sceneTickAction } from './dsl/scene/actions.js';
import assetMiddleware from './dsl/assets/middleware.js';

import listenerMiddleware from './listener-middleware';

const logger = (initialState) => {
  const predicate = (getState, action) => {
    if(action.type === sceneTickAction.toString()){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  return createLogger({predicate});
};

const getMiddleWare = (initialState, history) => {
  const list = [];

  if(initialState.system.role === 'client'){
    const routerHistory = routerMiddleware(history);

    list.push(routerHistory);
    list.push(listenerMiddleware(assetMiddleware))


  list.push(logger(initialState));

  return list;
};


const configureStore = (initialState, history) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer(initialState),
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware.apply(this, getMiddleWare(initialState, history))
  );
}

export default configureStore
```

The actions are straight forward

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
export const assetsReceiveBinary = createAction('@ASSETS/RECEIVE_BINARY')
export const assetsFetchBinary = createAction('@ASSETS/FETCH_BINARY')
```

and the Reducers:

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { assetsFetchBinary, assetsReceiveBinary } from '../assets/actions.js';

export const assetReducer = (state, action) => handleActions({
  [assetsFetchBinary]: (state, action) => {
    if(state.assets[action.path]){ return state; }
    return {
      ...state,
      assets: {
        ...state.assets,
        [action.path]: {}
      }
    }
  },

  [assetsReceiveBinary]: (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      assets: {
        ...state.assets,
        [action.path]: {arrayBuffer: action.arrayBuffer}
      }
    }
  }
}, state)(state, action);

export default assetReducer;
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
createStore.js:27 Uncaught Error: modifiers may not emit actions
    at dispatch (createStore.js:27)
    at listener-middleware.js:10
    at middleware.js:13
    at Object.assetsFetchBinary (bindActionCreators.js:3)
    at CharacterView.jsx:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CharacterView.componentDidUpdate (CharacterView.jsx:20)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:11517)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:12294)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1195)
    at commitAllWork (react-dom.development.js:12415)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:12687)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:1299)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:1338)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:1195)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:12800)
    at scheduleUpdateImpl (react-dom.development.js:13185)
    at scheduleUpdate (react-dom.development.js:13124)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:9646)
    at Connect../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.ReactComponent.setState (react.development.js:
```

dispatch line 27 looks like:

```
  function dispatch (action) {
    if (!action || !isPlainObject(action)) throw new Error('action parameter is required and must be a plain object')
    if (!action.type || typeof action.type !== 'string') throw new Error('type property of action is required and must be a string')
    if (isEmitting) throw new Error('modifiers may not emit actions')
```

The `action` at that dispatch call looks like `{type: "@ASSETS/FETCH_BINARY"}`

Additionally, I invoke these actions in `componentDidMount` like the following:

```
class CharacterView extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.missingItemAssets){
      this.props.missingItemAssets.forEach((assetName) => {
        this.props.assetsFetchBinary(assetName);
      });
    }
  }
```

If I wrap the dispatch calls in a  `0` `setTimeout` it prevents the error.

```
class CharacterView extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.missingItemAssets){
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.missingItemAssets.forEach((assetName) => {
        this.props.assetsFetchBinary(assetName);
      });
      }, 0)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably you are facing this https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/184?

Comment: I think https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/723 is more accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you dispatch the actions in `componentDidMount`, but your example shows you're actually dispatching from `componentDidUpdate`.

```
class CharacterView extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(){ // <--- should be componentDidMount?
    if(this.props.missingItemAssets){
      this.props.missingItemAssets.forEach((assetName) => {
        this.props.assetsFetchBinary(assetName);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This might be causing your problem, assuming your example in the question is accurate.

Comment: oh boy looks like I did have the dispatch loop in both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` moving it to one has helped. I suppose that was causing double dispatch emission